# How to control the output size when exporting images from an InDesign Document?

Tags: extendscript

I have a script that loop through the document images and write them to the disk, but I would like to know how to control the output size of the images.  Right now images seems to be exported the same size as their source, with the exception where smaller images are getting up-scaled.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var images = doc.allGraphics;   
var documentPath = doc.filePath;

app.jpegExportPreferences.jpegColorSpace = JpegColorSpaceEnum.RGB;
app.jpegExportPreferences.jpegQuality = JPEGOptionsQuality.MAXIMUM;
app.jpegExportPreferences.exportResolution = 300;

for(var i=0; i < images.length; i++){
    filename = documentPath + "/image_" + (i+1) + ".jpg";
    var imageFile = new File(filename);
    images[i].exportFile(ExportFormat.JPG, imageFile, false);
}
```

Comment: You can set the resolution and jpeg quality which should affect the size of the output image. There's no direct way to specify how big you want it to be though...

Comment: Not doubting you, but really? Sometime I'm surprised of the things you can do with scripting, but other times I'm baffled on how they can miss the boat on something like this, especially knowing that they make the most popular graphic editor in the world.